# Serilog send mail if exception is thrown in specific assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm working on a asp.net core (2.2) app that contains multiple assemblies. 
For logging I use serilog for asp.net core.
Now there's a requirement to send a mail when an exception is thrown.
The crux is: The email shall only be sent if the exception is thrown in one specific assembly.
Is there a way to achieve this with the serilog email sink?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specific to the email sink, but any logger configuration. See this answer for quite a few examples. Classes and namespaces can be filtered as well, and you could have exceptions from other assemblies get logged via a different sink. like rolling file.
[Filter Serilog logs to different sinks depending on context source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516359/filter-serilog-logs-to-different-sinks-depending-on-context-source)

Comment: Thank you for your hint. The thread helped me to configure the logger, indeed. I'll add my configuration as additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the configuration for appsettings.json that meets the requirements:

```
 "Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Email" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Information",
                "System": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "File", // general logging
                "Args": {
                    "path": "", // ToDo: Add log path
                    "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] ({Application}/{MachineName}/{EnvironmentUserName}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    "rollingInterval": "Day",
                    "shared": true
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "Logger",
                "Args": {
                    "configureLogger": {
                        "WriteTo": [
                            {
                                "Name": "Email",
                                "Args": {
                                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
                                    "outputTemplate": "{Message}{NewLine}{NewLine}Zeitpunkt: {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}{NewLine}Klasse: {SourceContext}{NewLine}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                                    "FromEmail": "{email address}", // ToDo: Add DefaultMailAddress
                                    "ToEmail": "{email address}", // ToDo: Add recipient mail addresses (separator: ; or ,)
                                    "MailServer": "", // ToDo: Add host
                                    "MailSubject": "", // ToDo: Add mail subject
                                    "NetworkCredentials": {
                                        "userName": "", // ToDo: Add UserName
                                        "password": "" // ToDo: Add Password
                                    },
                                    "Port": 25, // ToDo: Add Port
                                    "EnableSsl": true,
                                    "IsBodyHtml": true
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "Filter": [
                            {
                                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                                "Args": {
                                    "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Assembly.Namespace.')"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithEnvironmentUserName" ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "My.Application"
        }
    }
```