# Separate log into multiple logs files

Tags: serilog

I trying to configure Serilog to separate normal logs and entity framework logging.
Here is my serilog configuration:

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [
  "Serilog.Settings.Configuration",
  "Serilog.Sinks.File"
],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Debug",
    "System": "Warning"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "RollingFile",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "LogFile",
            "Args": {
              "textFormatter": "JsonFormatter",
              "fileSizeLimitBytes": 2147483648,
              "retainedFileCountLimit": 5
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "pathFormat": "log-{Date}.log",
      "logDirectory": ".",
      "Filter": [
        {
          "Name": "ByExcluding",
          "Args": {
            "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.')"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "RollingFile2",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "LogFile2",
            "Args": {
              "textFormatter": "JsonFormatter",
              "fileSizeLimitBytes": 2147483648,
              "retainedFileCountLimit": 5
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "pathFormat": "log-DB-{Date}.log",
      "logDirectory": ".",
      "Filter": [
        {
          "Name": "ByIncluding",
          "Args": {
            "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.')"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] ({CorrelationToken}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }
  }
],
"Enrich": [
  "FromLogContext",
  "WithMachineName",
  "WithProcessId",
  "WithThreadId",
  "WithHttpRequestId"
]
```

}

I do not get a second log file.
I base myself on this post to realize my configuration [Filter Serilog logs to different sinks depending on context source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516359/filter-serilog-logs-to-different-sinks-depending-on-context-source)

What did I not understand in the serilog configuration?
I find a lot of configuration examples via the code but very little via the appsettings.json.
I prefer to use appsetting.json

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to setup up sub loggers, not rolling files. You have two entries in your `WriteTo` array, but both are `"Name": "RollingFile"`. Change them to be `"Name": "Logger"` and then move the filter configs into the respective `configureLogger` sections of these sub loggers. Something like this:

```
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "log-{Date}.log",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 5,
                  "fileSizeLimitBytes": 2147483648,
                }
              }
            ],
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.')"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "log-db-{Date}.log",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 5,
                  "fileSizeLimitBytes": 2147483648,
                }
              }
            ],
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.')"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
```

In my tests there are still some `Microsoft.AspNetCore` and `Microsoft.Extensions` namespaces coming through in the second filter - so not sure if `ByIncluding` is blocking like `ByExcluding` is. And I'm not sure what other filter types are available for this.

**Update**

Just saw elsewhere that this appears to another type of filter that you can try: `"Name": "ByIncludingOnly"`.

Comment: Thank you. I think that must be it. I test and valid as soon as possible.