# How to configure multiple sinks to each have their own minimum log levels (based on namespace)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

See my example below, a default ASP.NET Core logging setup where the default `loglevel` is "Information" but for `ApplicationInsights` the `loglevel` for the Microsoft namespace is Warning:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
```

This is useful because I don't want to log Health requests to App Insights, for example. Not sending them to App Insights will result in a smaller bill!

Now, I can't really figure out how to do this with `Serilog`. I use the console and the app insights sinks. It seems like the `minimumLevel` is configured for the entire serilog logger, not on a sink basis.

---

Edit: **I have given up on this matter because it's too complex for my use case!**

I have given up on trying to achieve this with Serilog because .net 5.0 logging has improved a lot; I don't need Serilog anymore.

I have achieved my wish to NOT log health requests to App Insights with the following code:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information"
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation": "Warning",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Console": {
    "FormatterName": "Simple",
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "FormatterOptions": {
      "SingleLine": false,
      "TimestampFormat": "[yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss] "
    }
  }
},
```

`IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` and `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` are added because those would log some information that I don't need in App Insights because they are already logged as `Request`.

The console will log everything for clarity and deeper debugging if necessary.

Furthermore, to prevent App Insights from still saving the "Health" requests every couple seconds, I have used [this blog post from Jim Aho](https://blog.steadycoding.com/azure-application-insights-without-noise-from-health-checks-and-swagger/) to prevent App Insights from saving certain requests. Please note that I do use some null checks because sometimes the URL can be null depending on the telemetry.

```
/// <summary>
/// Stops certain requests from being logged to App Insights to prevent noise and save money.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Based on https://blog.steadycoding.com/azure-application-insights-without-noise-from-health-checks-and-swagger/
/// </remarks>
public class IgnoreRequestPathsTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private readonly ITelemetryProcessor _next;

    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _pathsToIgnore = new[]
    {
        "/health",
        "/swagger"
    };

    private static readonly StringComparison _stringComparison = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

    public IgnoreRequestPathsTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (ShouldFilterOutTelemetry(item))
        {
            return;
        }

        _next.Process(item);
    }

    private bool ShouldFilterOutTelemetry(ITelemetry item)
    {
        return item is RequestTelemetry request && _pathsToIgnore.Any(x => request.Url?.AbsolutePath?.StartsWith(x, _stringComparison) == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want Serilog's sub-logger feature. But having not used it I can't say for certain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter Serilog logs to different sinks depending on context source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516359/filter-serilog-logs-to-different-sinks-depending-on-context-source)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Hm, that is something I could attempt, although it seems rather cumbersome. I will give this a try! If someone else encounters this issue and I do not respond if that solution works, give me a reminder to respond :).

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your assistance. I have decided to not continue using Serilog; it's gains were minimal since improved logging in .net 5.0 so I switched to this. It seems so much more complex to set up different logging levels for namespaces for different sinks than for basic .net 5.0 logging. 

Furthermore, I have used https://blog.steadycoding.com/azure-application-insights-without-noise-from-health-checks-and-swagger/ to prevent App Insights from logging requests that I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Sink configuration methods usually provide a `restrictedToMinimumLevel` parameter that can be passed. (it cannot enable levels that are disabled at the global Serilog pipeline level, though)

This parameter is also available through the JSON configuration.

**More info in the wiki:** https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#overriding-per-sink

**You can find an example here:** https://github.com/tsimbalar/serilog-settings-comparison/blob/master/docs/README.md#sinks---restrictedtominimumlevel

**GH issue:** https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/135

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your assistance. I have decided to not continue using Serilog; it's gains were minimal since improved logging in .net 5.0 so I switched to this. It seems so much more complex to set up different logging levels for namespaces for different sinks than for basic .net 5.0 logging. 

Furthermore, I have used https://blog.steadycoding.com/azure-application-insights-without-noise-from-health-checks-and-swagger/ to prevent App Insights from logging requests that I don't need.