# How do I separate Serilog Logging output by the class where logging happens?

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, serilog

I am somewhat of an amateur with C# and am working on a .NET Framwork 4.7.2 WPF app where its primary purpose is to allow the user to run code from a class (all of which are kept in a "Scripts" folder in the program) that will perform a certain set of tasks in an imbedded browser. I am using Serilog for logging, and right now, my program is set up in my `App.xaml.cs` file to output all logging to a "Logs" folder, as shown below:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("./Logs/Log - .log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .WriteTo.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .CreateLogger();
```

The program generates a data folder for each of the classes kept in the "Scripts" folder in order to store input/output data. Each of these classes also use Serilog in order to log various things with the scripts as they run. **Is there a way that I could have Serilog save any logging done in these script classes to a separate log file**, which would then be located in the data folder of each respective class? The purpose of this is to preserve anything like `Log.Information("Finished task #1...");` and any errors with the code in the script in its own `.log` file so that it can be accessed and studied later by the user within the program.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516359/filter-serilog-logs-to-different-sinks-depending-on-context-source) for a way to filter logging based on classes, however, it looks like I'd have to manually put in this block of code for every script that I have:

```cs
.WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
                .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource<MyClass>())
                .WriteTo.RollingFile("logs/DBStats-{Date}.log", outputTemplate: "{Message}{NewLine}"))
```

These script classes will constantly be added and removed to the program as the user wishes, so I don't think this would work. I want any logging done within any of the script classes to automatically get written in that script's respective data folder.

I have also looked into [Serilog sub-loggers](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/), but have not figured out a way to use it to solve this problem.

Comment: Is there a way to identify all the script classes? (e.g. are they all under the same namespace? do they all inherit from a certain interface?) If so, you can probably scan for them and automate the `Filter` config.

Comment: Aternatively, try the [`ContextRollingFile`](https://github.com/sschutten/serilog-sinks-contextrollingfile) sink

Comment: @NPras All of the scripts inherit from a "ScriptBase" class. Could you point me in the right direction on how this filter could be automated?  Regarding `ContextRollingFile`, isn't the line `.WriteTo.File("./Logs/Log - .log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,...` in my first block of code doing exactly that?

Comment: `ContextRollingFile` is probably easier. It is a different sink to the `File` sink you're using. It allows you to use the log `Context` (usually your Class) in the file name/location. How are you using the logger in your script classes? If you use dependency injection, each script logger will already be enriched with the context. If you're using the static logger, each script will need to initialise their own Context `ILogger logger = Lor.ForContext(this.GetType); `

Comment: PS. `ContextRollingFile` is convenient but also has a pretty fat dependency tree and may bring in a whole bunch of libraries you don't need.  I'll, get you an example of building your own `Filter` without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do when configuring the logger, is to scan for all your script classes, and setting up Filters for them.

Based on your comment, we'll assume your classes look something like this:

```cs
public abstract class ScriptBase {
  protected ILogger logger;

  // Enrich the logger with SourceContext, in this case, the class type.
  // Child classes will be enriched with their own class names.
  public ScriptBase() { logger = Log.ForContext(this.GetType()); }
  
  public void Test(string s) {
    logger.Debug($"{s} debug");
    logger.Information($"{s} info");
    logger.Error($"{s} error");
  }
}
public class ScriptOne : ScriptBase { }
public class ScriptTwo : ScriptBase { }
```

We can then use the SourceContext to set up `Matching.FromSource()` filters.
This will assume your Script classes are loaded on startup, and you're not doing dynamic DLL loading on runtime.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Filters;

class Program {
  // Include Context in the template, to make the `Everything` log easier to read.
  const string template = "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";
  const RollingInterval interval = RollingInterval.Day;
  const string logDir = "c:/temp/logs"; // or wherever

  static void Main() {
    // We'll build up the Logger Config in a few steps.
    var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
      // Allow Debug and above globally. We can override this per sink later.
      .MinimumLevel.Debug()
      ;

    // Step 1. Find ALL classes inheriting from ScriptBase.
    var scriptTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
      .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
      .Where(typ => typeof(ScriptBase).IsAssignableFrom(typ))
      ;

    // Step 2. For each of the classes found above, 
    // configure the directory using filters.
    foreach (var type in scriptTypes) {
      logConfig = logConfig
        .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
          // Filter by the class name
          .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource(type.FullName))
          // And use it as subdirectory
          .WriteTo.File($"{logDir}/{type.Name}/Log-.log",
            rollingInterval: interval, outputTemplate: template
          )
        );
    }

    // Step 3. The rest of the config.
    logConfig = logConfig
      // Global file sink for everything
      .WriteTo.File($"{logDir}/EverythingLog-.log",
        rollingInterval: interval, outputTemplate: template,
        // Let's only log Info for the global file
        restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information
      )
      // And maybe restrict the Console sink to Warnings/Errors
      .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning)
      ;

    // Use the config above to initialise the logger.
    Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();

    // Now let's test the different scripts.
    new ScriptOne().Test("Hello");
    new ScriptTwo().Test("World");
  }
}
```

---

### Edit 2023-11-28

Now that we know how to roll it by hand, we'll do it the easy way with [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map). This should generalise the case a bit more, as you don't have to pre-scan your assemblies to create individual rules.

```
static void Main() {
  var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()

    // File sink for everything
    .WriteTo.File($"{logDir}/EverythingLog-.log",
      rollingInterval: interval, outputTemplate: template)

    // Map sink for each Context-enriched logs
    .WriteTo.Map(
      "SourceContext",  //< Property we get when using Log.ForContext()
      (srcContext, writeTo) => writeTo.File( // Map to a File sink
        $"{logDir}/{srcContext}/Log-.log", // ..in a subdirectory
        rollingInterval: interval, outputTemplate: template),
      sinkMapCountLimit: 10) //< See doc for Serilog.Sinks.Map
    ;

  Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();

  new ScriptOne().Test("Hello");
}
```

**Note:** `Log.ForContext()` will enrich logged items with a `"SourceContext"` by default, which may be good enough for this. But non-script SourceContexts (if you decide to enrich non-script items) will also be caught by the Map, logged in their own subdir, which may or may not be desirable.

You could create your own property name for Scripts and their descendants to give them their own context property, e.g.

```
// Context property named "ScriptName" instead of "SourceContext"
public ScriptBase() { 
  logger = Log.ForContext("ScriptName", this.GetType());
}

// Use ScriptName in template
template = "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {ScriptName}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";

// And in the Map configuration
.WriteTo.Map("ScriptName", .. );
```

Comment: Perfect, this works, thank you!

For now, my program loads my script classes at startup, as your code perfectly handles. However, the plan is to do dynamic DLL loading at runtime later on. What would you suggest doing regarding this logging initialization for that case?

Comment: @NinjaPedroX, I've edited the answer and added an alternative using `Serilog.Sinks.Map`, which will make your life a lot easier (and should work more generally). I don't use it often, so I've kinda forgotten about it, sorry! I hope the original answer still has at least some educational value :)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, many thanks to you!